# How to retrieve index that is a root cause of a duplicate index error

Tags: mongodb

When inserting a document in a collection with multiple unique indexes, how could I retrieve which index is the root cause of the duplicate index error ?

Comment: What if it is multiple indexes causing the problem? Wouldn't you just do a `getIndexes()` and from there see what field which threw the error exists in what indexes?

Comment: You mean a duplicate key error? The name of the index should be returned by getLastError. For example, the name of the index is foo_1: E11000 duplicate key error index: test.foo.$foo_1  dup key: { : 2.0 }

Comment: In fact, getLastError returns this error in "err" field (in a String format), but I expected that the index could be in a specific fields as "indexes".

Comment: It will fail on the first index to throw an error at the moment, maybe there is a JIRA for it somewhere, can't find one